# django uuid or hashid field for primary keys? and how to prefix the generated ids with say "cust_"

Tags: django, django-models, primary-key, uuid, django-model-field

I am currently using [django-shortuuidfield](https://pypi.org/project/django-shortuuidfield/) to generate a unique UUID primary key on the **Customer** model as shown below

```py
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_id = ShortUUIDField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
```

This guarantees that the `customer_id` field is unique with space and time. However, this generates an id similar to `B9fcKdMDHbwKCBoADjbNyA` and I want to prefix this with `cust_` to make it like this `cust_B9fcKdMDHbwKCBoADjbNyA`. How do I achieve this without making multiple db calls?

I also looked into [django-hashid-field](https://pypi.org/project/django-hashid-field/) which supports prefixes out of the box but this does not guarantee UUID, and on a larger scale, we may run into unique contain failed issues that are not desirable.

Any thoughts on this? Let me know...

Comment: Is this a seperate field from the pk/id? I'd recommend it to be. For the `customer_id`, you could append your prefix in the save method, depending on when that uuid is generated.

Comment: So you suggest that the Customer model have an id field by default and also customer_id field with ShortUUIDField() and id can be hidden in serializer? Perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a stale thread, but I just recently came across this problem myself. I ended up just forking and modifying ShortUUIDField module to include a prefix and suffix optionally. Kind of a hacky job I have to admit, but I thought I'd share for posterity.

https://github.com/nick-fournier/django-customshortuuidfield

use like:

```
class Business(models.Model):
     id = CustomShortUUIDField(primary_key=True, prefix="biz_")
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I will take a look!